# why use of % symbol in like operator of mysql query converted to ampersand '&'?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Below query i have written in codeigniter using mysql method to get user details using LIKE operator and  % symbol to get data  but when  I run  query it is changing '26/04' to  '&/04%' automatically, i have added image also to get Clarity so my question is why this is happening so ?

[image]

```
$userdob='26/04';


$_SESSION['date_of_birth']='26/04/1994';

$location='Mumbai';

$users = "AND dob  LIKE '%" . $userdob . "%'  AND dob NOT LIKE '%" . $_SESSION['date_of_birth'] . "%' ";


SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid NOT IN(" . $_SESSION['id'] . ") AND user_location LIKE '%" . $city_key . "%' " . $users. " " ;
```

Comment: `%` is mysql's wildcard (usally `*` across other languages - but in MySQL it means 'all') - so the query will look for all fields that include the string `$userddob` - as for converting to `&` - no idea, maybe a `str_replace` somewhere? couldn't tell you - though I think it's because you have your wildcards outside the doublequotes - change to `LIKE '"%'. $usrdob .'%"'` and see what happens

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs i tried this way but getting problem and one more thing  i am not doing any str_replace .

Comment: @Saranya Rajendran do you got the reason why it  replacing  date to &

Comment: what happens if you try this?
`$this->db->where_not_in('user_id', array((int) $_SESSION['id']));
$this->db->like('user_location ', $city_key, 'both');
$this->db->like('dob', $userdob, 'both');
$this->db->not_like('dob', $_SESSION['date_of_birth'], 'after');#if session date is like "yyyy-mm-dd" else set to standar db date format
$sql = $this->db->get('users');
#if you only wait for one record use row() else result()
log_message('info', 'DEBUG QUERY' . "\n" . $this->db->last_query());
return $sql->row();`.
What is the query it build?